# Use Sort Whilst Still Retaining Keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

When I use the sort function in php it deletes all of the keys. What's an alternative method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [asort](http://php.net/asort) function is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, seems like a bit of an after thought from the PHP developers.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `asort` instead of `sort` which keeps your key associations intact:

http://php.net/asort

Answer (score 3):

[asort — Sort an array and maintain index association](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php). I guess that is what you're searching for.